# How to seprate pargraph and the table in office-js?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I'm having the following code

```
let p1 = context.document.body.insertParagraph(data[i],"end");
p1.style = "Ex-1";

let table = context.document.body.insertTable(2,2,"end",json_data);
table.style = 'Table-Style';
```

In the above code `table` using the `p1` style also. But if I insert the `normal` style into the another one paragraph it is working good but new lines is coming because of the new added paragraph, check the below code

```
let p1 = context.document.body.insertParagraph(data[i],"end");
p1.style = "Ex-1";

let p2 = context.document.body.insertParagraph("","end");
p2.style = "Normal";

let table = context.document.body.insertTable(2,2,"end",json_data);
table.style = 'Table-Style';
```

Actually I want separate the paragraph and table How to fix this issue.?

Comment: There's a body.insertTable method that takes 4 parameters, but the insertParagraph method takes only 2. You're calling insertParagraph as if it was insertTable. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Try using "before" instead of "end" to place the table "inside" p2.  (And, of course, use insertTable to insert the table, not insertParagraph.)

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks. Some typo. Question edited

Comment: what do you mean by "separating the paragraph and the table"?